# Searching key/value pair from one object to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of objects and one object in JavaScript:

```
var data = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1}, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}];
var myFilter = {"a": 1, "b": 2};
```

...and would like to use `myFilter` object as a filter to the array of objects to create a new array of objects if and only if the object at least matches or contain the `myFilter` key/value pairs.

Any recommendation how can I go ahead and put it into code? I need to create a new array that was filtered from `data` using the `myFilter` key/value pair.

I was able to do this but `myFilter` only contains 1 key/value pair.

My expected new array is:

```
var newArr = [];
newArr = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}];
```

Comment: If you did this for single pair, wouldn't be hard to do for many - you just need a loop inside a loop. For enumeration of object properties `for(a in b)` construction used (where b is an object).

Comment: @VallyN I tried doing that as well, but the tendency is will create a duplicate of the current object because the second key/value pair is a match as well.

Comment: Both, CodeSir and Andreas aswered to your question, have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this:

```js
var data = [{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }]
var myFilter = { "a": 1, "b": 2 }

var myFilterFunction = function(obj) {
  for (var p in myFilter) {
    if (obj[p] !== myFilter[p]) return false
  }
  return true
}

var newArr = data.filter(myFilterFunction)

document.write(JSON.stringify(newArr))
```

---

A more universal approach would be this `filterFuncByObj(filterObj)` function, wich takes any custom filter object:

`data.filter(filterFuncByObj(myFilter))`:

```js
var data = [{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }]
var myFilter = { "a": 1, "b": 2 }

var newArr = data.filter(filterFuncByObj(myFilter))

// Demo Output
document.write(JSON.stringify(newArr))


function filterFuncByObj(filterObj) {
  return function(obj) {
    for (var p in filterObj) {
      if (obj[p] !== filterObj[p]) return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also pass filter set as argument.

Comment: @VallyN you are right, it would be better. I modifyed to code

Comment: @CodeiSir this is amazing! Thank you!

Comment: @BillyWilsonArante your wellcome! I also added an more universal filter `filterFuncByObj(filterObj)`

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) this could be one way to go

```js
var data = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1}, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}];
var myFilter = {"a": 1, "b": 2};

var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return Object.keys(myFilter).every(function(f) {
        return d[f] === myFilter[f];
    })
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [lodash](https://lodash.com) way, just in case:

```js
var data = [{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }];
var myFilter = { "a": 1, "b": 2 };

var newArr = _.filter(data, myFilter);
document.write(JSON.stringify(newArr, null, 3));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```